# Use custom View with multiple Controllers in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In `Phoenix`, is there some way that I can specify which `View` to use instead of letting the `Controller` inflect from the namespace?

I have multiple controllers and for each controller's view the methods are same. I would like to create a single view and use it with (almost) all of my controllers.

**Is this possible?** And more importantly, **is this a bad practice or justified in my situation?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `put_view/2` to set the view module. It is not bad practice given your description. You can put the following code inside your controller:

```
plug :put_view, MyApp.TheView
```

Or you can modify the view for a single function inside your controller, e.g.:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_view(MyApp.TheView)
    |> render("index.html")
  end
```